# What are the scriptures which every Islam follower should abide by?

Tags: scripture

My first question is what are the scriptures every Muslim (or Islam follower) should abide by? In other words, what scriptures are considered the fundamental/basic on which Islam is based on? Or What are the very important scriptures that are considered as highest/top?

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE. Please take our introductory tour to understand how this site works and which questions are accepted here. http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour They must, among other conditions, be based on some research effort with answers that are not readily accessible by running a search engine, unlike the question that you have just asked for Wikipedia has a specific entry that answers it exactly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Islamic_texts

Comment: @infatuated ok; I see that Quran is believed most important but I [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_holy_books) that there are other three books Tawrat, Zabur and Injil which are pre-Quran. Note that as I'm new to learn Islam, I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: @infatuated as question is asking about "scriptures every Muslim (or Islam follower) should abide by" so taurah and other old books before quran are not meant to be followed by muslims. Those were books for their times, quran is the latest book we all are supposed to follow.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal You mean book should be followed according to time? (i.e scriptures are written for or applicable to specific time only)?

Comment: Old scriptures were for their time. Quran is the last scripture and code from Allah for mankind. And all old scriptures had indication of this that last message will come, but those scriptures got corrupted and most of that information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

When you say **scriptures**, than let us be all clear, that **Quran is the word of Allah, sent down on prophet Muhammad ﷺ by Jibrael A.s. And as Muslims this is the most important book we have to follow, indeed this book is basis and Allah promise will not be corrupted until the day of judgement!!**

Than in Quran, you will find **Allah's command on following prophet** in multiple places, **how can we follow prophet in present time? we will look for his sayings, actions etc. Those are saved in books of ahadees.** There is complete SCIENCE of ahadees and how they are judged to be authentic etc. In short, we can trust all authentic ahadees. So, ahadees should be followed, they contain all the sayings, doings, routines etc of prophet.

Now, **ahadees are a large collection**. As one can expect that everything(his saying/doing/routines etc) in a person's life is written, it will be a huge stack... So are ahadees. And every Muslim can't find the thing he is looking for in ahadees easily(because of their volume). So, he will need to follow someone he trust. You may call it taqleed or whatever. But, he must leave anything which he finds is contradicting with something in Quran and hadees, and after talking about it and discussing it, his heart is telling that he(whom he is following) is wrong in this particular matter and some other view is right about this. Than one must follow the view(he thinks is right).

**So, as of scriptures(as the question ask about) these 2 are main scriptures from where each islamic teaching is derived/taken from.**

I hope this answers the question, although i am not sure what you are actually looking for but i answered what i understood in question.

### Allah knows best

Comment: You've said 2 main scriptures. I understand that one is Quran but which is second one and what is ahadees?

Comment: as i said, we call hadees "the sayings, doings and routines of prophet muhammad s.a.w.w", hadees means "saying" in arabic, but by its usage we include all the routines, doings etc also in hadees. And there are collections of those ahadees narrated by the companions of prophet. you can find some main collection on sunnah.com

Answer (score 1):

### What are the scriptures which every Islam follower should abide by?

There is only one which is the Quran. There are other scriptures in Islam but they were revealed before the Quran and no longer apply to Muslims. The Tawrat was revealed to mosses as a guidance for him people. All the followers of mosses followed it. After it, Allah (The God) revealed the Injil to Jesus which became obligatory for his followers.

Few hundreds years after that, Allah revealed the final revelation to Muhammad, the Quran. All the scriptures that were revealed before it (e.g. the Tawrat, the Injil) were abrogated after its revelation. Allah say in the Quran (what means):

> We do not abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten except that **We
>   bring forth [one] better than it or similar to it.** Do you not know
>   that Allah is over all things competent?

Let me give an example to clarify how it works:

A student first studies in kindergarten, then grade school, then High school, then collage and then he studies in University. A student can't directly admit into university with no prior education. And a student of University doesn't study the books of schools or collages.

Similarly, the Quran is the highest level of revelation which is revealed for all of humanity. Those who follow the Quran don't need to follow previous scriptures. You might ask, why didn't Allah reveal the Quran to the people of mosses or Jesus?

Cause human civilization didn't reach the level to understand the Quran at that point of time. Just like a school student can't understand or have difficulty understanding University curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one such scripture in Islam which is the Quran. If someone who claims to be Muslim says he doesn't belief in it then he wouldn't be regarded as one cause all Muslims agree that the anyone who rejects the Quran rejects Islam as well.

All the copies of the Quran are same. They are all written in the same way with the same arabic letters.